# view alignment for ios view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, view

So I am trying to align a `HStack`in the center of the screen and have bell icon aligned on the right side of the screen.

Below is the code I have:

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Spacer()
            if(self.top == 0) {
                UserFeedView()
            } else {
                MapView()
            }
            VStack() {
                Spacer().frame(maxHeight: 80)
                HStack() {
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.top = 0
                        }) {
                            Text("Feed").foregroundColor(self.top == 0 ? .black : Color.black.opacity(0.45))
                                .fontWeight(self.top == 0 ? .bold : .none)
                                .padding(.vertical )
                        }
                        Text("|")
                            .font(.system(size:20))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.3))
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            self.top = 1
                            
                        }) {
                            Text("Map").foregroundColor(self.top ==  1 ? .black : Color.black.opacity(0.45))
                                .fontWeight(self.top == 1 ? .bold : .none)
                                .padding(.vertical )
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 23)
                    .background(.ultraThinMaterial, in : RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16.0))
                    Image(systemName: "bell")
                        .frame(alignment: .trailing)
                        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()

        }
    }
```

and the result:

[image]

As you can see, the `selector`between feed and map is not centered in the middle of the screen and the bell icon is not properly aligned on the right side. If I remove the bell icon, the `Hstack selector`is perfectly centered

Comment: Why do you need the additional VStack? Can't you just offset it from the top by using padding instead?

Comment: i am new in swift ui so I do not know all the layouts management

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to structure the code something like this:

```swift
HStack {
  // buttons etc.
}
// apply the formatting to your button group, e.g.
.background(.ultraThinMaterial, in : RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16.0))
// then extend its frame out to the width of the screen
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
// then place the bell as an overlay, aligning with the full-width frame
.overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
  Image(systemName: "bell")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the easiest way is to have your `HStack` use the full available width and then set the bell image on the right using an overlay:

```swift
    VStack {
        Spacer().frame(maxHeight: 80)
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            // Buttons go here as before
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 23)
        .background(.ultraThinMaterial, in : RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16.0))
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
            Image(systemName: "bell").padding()
        }
        Spacer()
    }
```

If you know the size of the bell image (including padding) then you could also do it by using padding on the left to balance the width of the image on the right. That way you can keep the selector centered. But I would suggest, an overlay is simpler.

BTW, just in case you didn't know, you can set `.pickerStyle(.segmented)` on a native `Picker` to get a similar kind of selector, instead of rolling your own.